# Alert for when a contract is ending

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow2013

How do I create an alert on SharePoint 2013 for when the contracts are about to expire?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow.

Workflows start on item creation, so you will have to pause them (use Pause until activity):
[image]

and then send an email to a person you wanted to be alerted (Send an Email activity)
[image]

It's an ok solution if you don't have many items or if you need to pause for a short time. Otherwise keep in mind that every workflow is running until the email is sent.

Another solution you could check out is Information Management Policy (library>settings). It allows you to e.g. delete items after a month or two, or e.g. start a workflow after given time. Depending on the size of your library/list, it may be more optimal than pausing an SPD workflow.